# Singleton Scala actor?

Tags: scala, object, singleton, actor

Simple question. Can I do this:

```
object Xyz extends Actor { ... }
```

or do Actors have to be classes with instances?

Comment: Thought: If I couldn't do this, I could just have an `object` which has the actor as a member...

Comment: Thought: Why not try it and see

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `object` keyword is essentially creating an anonymous class and a single instance of that class. So yes, that code will be fine - `Xyz` will be a reference to an object that is an Actor.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I did try this and it compiled fine, but the messages don't seem to be getting received by the actor.

Comment: Looks like that problem was unrelated to `object` or not. Solved.

Comment: with scala 2.8, I get this error:

object creation impossible, since method act in trait Reactor of type ()Unit is not defined

Answer (score 12):

Object extending `Actor` works fine.

Perhaps you forgot to `start` the actor? (That's a mistake I did initially)

```
object Xyz extends Actor {
    start

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, I had forgotten to start the actor (but was too embarrassed to say...). Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Perhaps you should mark this as the correct answer to help future visitors

Comment: Hi HRJ. Tricky one. Lachlan answered the question correctly first. The reason I asked was motivated by the fact that I hadn't started the actor but strictly that wasn't in my question. I think I'll stick with Lachlan's answer for the sake of correctness, sorry.

Comment: In recent versions of Akka I seem to get ` not found: value start` with the suggestion "Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [server.AutowireServer$] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation." So far, the documentation and other comments makes me wonder if this is still possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend the following 'fire and forget' pattern:

Actor.actor { doStuff }

Your operation will run in a separate thread to conclusion.